# Does the VSCode Remote Tunnels support opening GUIs?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote, tunnel, visual-studio-code-server

I've searched the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/tunnels), the [GitHub issues](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues) and tried the [Remote X11 extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=spadin.remote-x11) as well, but none of work or mention anything about X11 forwarding through VSCode Tunnels.

Is there any way to do it, or is it not possible yet?

Answer (score 1):

If you're running R or Python, you can install Jupyter extension and choose R kernel / Python kernel, and the graphical results (i.e. plots) should be displayed, instead of having to be X11-forwarded.